# How to Python tkinter image insert relative path method

Tags: python, tkinter

There's something I want to make, so I'm learning tkinter.

The relative route is not recognized.

Example code.
Suppose that hyunju.png is in the corresponding .py folder.

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("tk")
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=400, height=600)
canvas.pack()
gazou = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="hyunju.png")
canvas.create_image(200, 300, image=gazou)
root.mainloop()
```

> tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "hyunju.png": no such file or
> directory

I'm having a hard time because if I use Copy path, there will be a problem when I share or change files.

The editor used is VS code and OS is window 10.

help for me thank you

Comment: It may be because the *working directory* is not the same as the script path when you execute the script in VS code.  Try opening a command shell, change directory to the script path and execute the script.

Comment: @acw1668 Would you be more specific?
I need a video or information that I can refer to.

Comment: I don't know how to be more specific but the [image](https://imgur.com/a/yZjeYZf) can tell you that inside VS code, you can have the current directory not as the same as the script path.

Comment: @acw1668 Through some experiments, as acw1668 said, there seems to be a problem with VScode. It worked normally in Pycham.
I understand a little what you mean. But I need to find more ways.
Just in case, please don't close this question. The questions below are also valuable. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Depending on **hardcoded relative paths** should be avoided in this scenario, as they're often times **unreliable**. Depending on your **IDE** and even **OS** it may work or not.

Thus, You should choose a more dynamic better an approach like the following:

```
import pathlib, os
img_file_name = "hyunju.png"
current_dir = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve() # current directory
img_path = os.path.join(current_dir, img_file_name) # join with your image's file name
```

As long as the image file is guaranteed to be in the same directory as the script being executed, it does not matter what **IDE / OS** you're on - it will work.

Comment: You can use `pathlib` to join path: `img_path = current_dir.joinpath(img_file_name)` or even `img_path = current_dir / img_file_name`, then you don't need to import `os` module.

Comment: relative paths aren't unreliable, they are completely deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I don't know if it might be the same case for you, just check that you are opening the whole project and not just the .py file if you are working on an IDE like, for example, Visual Studio Code, because else it won't be able to find any relatives paths

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32601249)